# What discussion alternatives have you used with SharePoint 2010…?

Tags: untagged

I'm just wondering what solutions people have implemented for discussion forums in SharePoint 2010.

Do you mostly opt to use the out-of-the-box discussion lists and web parts?

Are there alternative web parts that you have used?

Have you gone with a completely different solution for featuring discussions?

Answer (score 1):

I've gone with standard lists and web parts for almost everything. Having no training for Sharepoint and no test site to play around with and destroy, I can't really experiment. 
I've seen a few enterprise implementations of Sharepoint though, but I'm yet to see one that is accepted as the standard for document repositories, discussions, calendars, or anything else. I guess the big question I have is what discussion board can be implemented that people want to use.